# Parallels Plesk shows Default Page

Tags: wordpress, hosting, plesk, parallels

I uploaded Wordpress files from the old server to Parallels Plesk in the httpdocs directory and deleted the index.html but when I open the site it still shows the default page of the parallels plesk panel.

How can I solve that?

Best Regards

Comment: Which Operating system and what version of Parallels Plesk you are using?. Following are some fixes suggested by Parallels you wish to refer:
http://kb.odin.com/en/118537
http://kb.odin.com/en/119507
http://kb.odin.com/en/113668

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that domain name is resolvable to correct IP address.
Try rebuilding the Apache configuration files for the domain:

/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-domain domain.com

Check possible redirection in .htaccess file.